# Can you `= delete` a templated function on a second declaration?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, nvcc, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T> int foo();
template <typename T> int foo() = delete;
```

is this valid C++11?

- GCC (9.1) says: Yes!
- clang (8.0) says: No!
- nvcc (9.2) says: No!
- MSVC (19.20) says: Yes! <sub>(in C++14 mode, it doesn't support C++11.)</sub>

... see it all on [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YNstQX).

so which compilers are right and which compilers are s@#$%e ? :-)

Comment: Well would be strange it to be valid as the first line says something like "well, there is a function called foo that is defined somewhere" which is exactly the contrary of delete.

Comment: @OznOg _@einpoklum_ notoriously asks very strange questions :). But finding that gcc bug is great!

Comment: no pb, that was just a chatty comment of mine; the question is completely valid to me.

Comment: MSVC also accepts this: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CFIEgb

Comment: This is not a standard C++

Comment: "delete" can only appear on the first declaration of a function

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Most flattering SE comment I've ever gotten! Thanks :-)

Comment: @JVApen: See edit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GCC and MSVC have a bug.

> **[dcl.fct.def.delete]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.delete#4) ... A deleted definition of a function shall be the first declaration of the function or, for an explicit specialization of a function template, the first declaration of that specialization...

Which I believe stands for instantiated declarations and definitions too. Since referring to a deleted function is a hard error, it must be declared as deleted asap.

Comment: Why "must" it be declared as deleted ASAP - as opposed to - before it is first referred to? Also, even if a deletion appeared later, a compiler could notice the error when it sees the deletion instead of when it sees the reference. But - accepting.

Comment: Also - is this still the case in C++14 and C++17? Just curious and I don't want to open another question.

Comment: Bug report [filed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90703) against GCC.

Comment: @einpoklum - The code referring to it could be between the first declaration and definition. Demanding it on the first declaration is just easiest I suppose. And seeing as I quoted n4659 (C++17, haven't noticed the tag), yes it is. I checked n3337 (c++11), the wording is the same.

Comment: @einpoklum: A virtual function has to reserve a slot in the vtable (in normal implementations).  Having it declared as non-deleted in one declaration and non-deleted in another might be considered incompatible declarations because of actual layout of something?  (Whether a function is virtual or not, you could imagine some strange implementation where some kind of mechanism is triggered for non-deleted function declarations.)  Or maybe this rule makes it easier to parse, if you don't have to support changing a non-deleted function to deleted after the fact.

Comment: @PeterCordes - A deleted definition is explicitly forbidden for virtual function overrides. You can't refer to a deleted function via a virtual call. It's purely a compile time thing.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ok, that rules out part of my wild guess.  But you could imagine a C++ implementation that did *something* for every non-deleted function it saw a declaration for.  A vtable would only be a loose analogy.  (Or the C++ standards committee could imagine that such an implementation *might* exist, and wanted to make things easier for it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: 1. C++ does not know anything about vtables and an implementation is not required to have any of those at all. 2. I'm talking about freestanding functions here; member functions are slightly different beasts. 3. Would you really allocate vtable slots when encountering  member function _template_ declarations? Wouldn't that mean an infinite number of vtable slots?

Comment: @einpoklum: Like I already said, a vtable is merely an example of something an implementation might process when encountering declarations.  Maybe it's too much of a stretch to imagine the C++ committee worrying about implementations that might have trouble with this mismatch *for any reason like this, not specifically vtables*; maybe they just forbid it because it would be inconsistent.

Comment: @einpoklum What if the deleted declaration is in another TU? It's okay for defaulted functions, but not for deleted.

Comment: @Rakete1111: What happens in another TU is irrelevant for compilation...

Comment: @einpoklum ? What do you mean?

Comment: One could argue that the cited paragraph talks about functions, and here we have a function template (I'm not sure I'm willing to be that one :-) ). The Standard in its current form allows *some* templates to be first declared and later defined as deleted: member function templates of a class template (since the implicit instantiation of the enclosing class template triggers the instantiation of declarations, but not definitions, of member templates). I wonder what the actual intent is here. As an additional data point, EDG in strict mode also rejects the code. cc @einpoklum

Comment: @bogdan - I'm not sure that not instantiating the definition is an allowance in this rule. It seems like only a delay for the point at which it must be checked. And as a data point on this, clang rejects an out of class definition outright https://wandbox.org/permlink/Iv0yelOWnx4Y7yaN

Comment: @Rakete1111: You only compile a single TU at a time, and any files going into another TUs are not considered during compilation.

Comment: @einpoklum What I mean is that if you declare the function in one TU, then that TU will think that there is a definition of it. If you then delete it in another one, the first TU has no idea that the function is actually deleted.

Comment: @Rakete1111: This is "not a problem" in the same sense that you could have conflicting definitions of a function in different TUs, and each will compile. It's on you to make sure this doesn't happen, anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller As far as I can tell, those are treated as real declarations and definitions, respectively, even if we're not allowed to write them. For example, looking at [DR2260](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2260), it seems that it was introduced to avoid issues related to this separation between declaration and definition points. Your example uses member functions, not member function templates. That being said, a similar example using templates is also rejected; moreover, it's also rejected by GCC :-).

Comment: We also have to consider the fact that requiring the deleted definition to be the first declaration for a template is not as useful as it is for non-template functions. You can have a deleted definition for the template, and then a non-deleted explicit specialization. This means that the compiler still has to check everything between the first template declaration and the point of instantiation to decide what definition to use.

Comment: Issues like trying to use a specialization before an explicit specialization is seen for it (either in the same TU or across TUs) are handled by paragraphs like [\[temp.point\]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.point#7), which make them ill-formed, NDR.

Comment: @bogdan - True. But then again it's nothing new when it comes to templates. One has to bring up temp.expl.spec/7 whenever this subject comes up :)

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was that we have such provisions for templates, so allowing a declaration before the deleted definition wouldn't introduce more problems (that I can see...). However, for a non-template function, once you've seen a (non-defining) declaration, it's OK to use it, there has to be a definition somewhere. Allowing that definition to be deleted would break the "it's OK to use it" part, so the rule makes sense for functions. I wonder if that's why templates are not specifically mentioned there, and also why they're specifically left out of the fix in the DR I mentioned above.